# How to exclude first of table's column from sort?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I use jQuery tablesorter for sorting tables columns.

If table's id is "#players"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

<table id="test" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>RowNumber</th>
            <th>Values1</th>
            <th>Values2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td>111</td>
            <td>1111</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2</th>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>222</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>3</th>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3333</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I enable sorting by

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#test").tablesorter({});
    })
</script>
```

Recently I got use case when 1st table's columns (row number) should not be EVER sorted, while I still want to have all other items sorted according to users's selection.

Is there any way to achieve that with jquery tablesorter?

Thank you.

P.S. The referenced question ([How to disable sorting on column in jQuery.tablesorter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942974/how-to-disable-sorting-on-column-in-jquery-tablesorter)) is not about excluding column from sorting, that is about preventing table from sorting on click on this column header. 
What I need is to not sort content in the 1st column while clicking on headers of other columns.

P.P.S. Question indeed is duplicate, but to another one: [Exclude a column from being sorted using jQuery tablesorter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437290/exclude-a-column-from-being-sorted-using-jquery-tablesorter)

Comment: *first of table* do you mean the header?

Comment: im assuming you mean you want the first row of data to not be affected by the sorting. have a look at adding a custom parser for tablesorter: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html and giving your first row the highest/lowest corresponding value as needed to make it always rise to the top :)

Comment: No, my 1st row is always in place and not modified. If I click on column header (1st row) table content is sorted by that row. RowNumber column is rearranged together with the rest of the content, but I do want to keep RowNumber always from 1 to 3...

Comment: Arun, you deleted wrong answer.. Would you mind to vote question for re-open?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want the first column to remain static (unsorted), while the the other columns are sorted? That is, given your example the first column would always be 1 > 2 > 3 ... etc regardless of the sorting applied to the other columns?

Comment: If so try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437290/exclude-a-column-from-being-sorted-using-jquery-tablesorter

Comment: Yeah, I need that. And referenced link should be a solution, though it doesn't work ... It least got an idea, thank you. will need to tune it a bit.